# What does it mean "to give the huffle of something"?

Tags: meaning, expressions

I've been reading **When We Were Very Young** by *A. A. Milne* and stumbled upon the expression `to give the huffle of something` in the **The Four Friends** poem.

Here's some context:

> Ernest started trumpeting, and cracked his manger,
>
> Leonard started roaring, and shivered his stall,
>
> James **gave the huffle of** a snail in danger
>
> And nobody heard him at all.

What does it mean "James **gave the huffle of** a snail in danger"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps it's a made-up nonsense word, which describes the (non-existent) noise of a snail

- An elephant "trumpets"
- A lion "roars"
- A snail "huffles"

The word "giving" is sometimes used in the context of creating an audible alarm, e.g. "he gave a cry of alarm" (although it is a bit literary or old-fashioned), or any other communication e.g. "he gave a signal to advance".

Answer (score 0):

It means "James gave the kind of huffle that a snail does when it's in danger" (whatever a 'huffle' may be).

A more common use of this construction is in phrases like "the groan of a man in pain".

Answer (score -1):

[huffle](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/huffle) can mean

> to blow in gusts

Snail not having any cry, Milne is describe James as making a sound by breathing outward like a gust of wind -- with little noise, as shown by the failure to be heard.